# Junit want to stop the method after certain amount of time

Tags: java, junit

I have a junit test class.The test class reads a file and sends a message to telnet server.The processing can take anywhere 1hr to 5hrs depending on the no of message in the file.I want this test class to stop after certain amount of time which is configured in a property file.Below is my code.

```
public void sendMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        final long timetorun = Long.valueOf(props.getMap().get("timetorun"))
                .longValue();

        try {

            System.out.println("duration : " + duration);
            while (duration < timetorun) {
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                duration = endTime - startTime;
                logger.info("Sending Message");
                telnetUtils.run(telnetClient);
                // sendMessage();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

suppose timetorun is 1hr
The problem here is if the telnetUtils.run(telnetClient); takes more than 1 hrs this logic will not work.

Can anybody give some help on how to,achive this.

Answer (score 4):

You may set a timeout on a test case. For example:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class TestTimeout {
    private long startAt;
    @Before
    public void before() {
        this.startAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    @After
    public void after() {
        System.out.println(String.format("Total time: %1$d ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - startAt));
    }
    @Test(timeout=1000)
    public void timeout() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

The test fails because of the timeout. It writes this in standard output:

```
Total time: 1001 ms
```

Comment: +1 You can change the 1000 to be a final value. A better solution would be to use a Timeout Rule, because then you can use non-final values.

Comment: Indeed a timeout rule is so much better. Everyday we learn something :). @hanmayya, have a look at [this](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/Timeout.html)